# Efficiently calculate mean value from files

Tags: matlab, mean

From a Monte-Carlo simulation I have a range of files, say: file_1.mat, file_2.mat,...,file_n.mat, where n is large. Each file contains one or several (maximum 3 if it matters) large 1D arrays in time of interest, say var1, var2, var3.

I am now as always interested in finding the mean value of these variables. My question is now, how do I do this in the most efficient way? The keyword here is efficiency. Below you will find the MWE which is done the standard way, but this is quite time consuming as the files are large and there are many.

I am programming in Matlab, however ideas presented in pseudo code is also very well received.

MWE:(The standard way)

```
meanVar1 = zeros(1,1e6); %I do not remember the exact size, just use 1e6
meanVar2 = zeros(1,1e6);
meanVar3 = zeros(1,1e6);
for i 1=1:n
    load(strcat('file_',int2str(i)),'var1','var2','var3')
    meanVar1 = meanVar1 + var1;
    meanVar2 = meanVar2 + var2;
    meanVar3 = meanVar3 + var3;
end
meanVar1 = meanVar1/n;
meanVar2 = meanVar2/n;
meanVar3 = meanVar3/n;
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `meanVar3 = zeros(1,1e6);` a vector? Are you missing the correct indexing within the loop? To me it looks like all the 1e6 will have the same values in your code in each iteration.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you are asking? On every loop I load new var1, var2 and var3. I want the sum of all those, which is initially stored in the variable meanVar1, meanVar2 and meanVar3 which is being updated in each loop. If you refer to that I use the term vector and make zeros(1,1e6) in stead of zeros(1e6,1), then this is just me abusing the term "vector". Note that var1 is a "vector" which size(var1)=[1,1e6]. Did this answer your question?

Comment: Sorry, I somehow dropped the information that you were reading 1D arrays. No clue how you could speed that up, unfortunately.